# How to set input and output shape for binary variables when using SimpleRNN in Keras?

Tags: python, input, keras, output, recurrent-neural-network

I'm using `SimpleRNN` to train a model with binary input of length 100 and binary output of length 100, meaning that my `X.shape=(nsamples, 100, 1)` and `y.shape=(nsamples, 100)`

When using the following code the model doesn't return error but learns very slowly and the loss stop decreasing after a number of epochs.

I also tried changing learning-rate which didn't help. I guess the critical problem may be with input and output shape.

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(
    SimpleRNN(
        output_dim=100,
        input_shape=(100, 1),
        return_sequences=False,
        activation='sigmoid'
    )
)
sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01, decay=0.0, nesterov=False)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd)
model.fit(X, y, epochs=500)
```

Comment: You can use RMSProp optimizer with a low learning rate like 0.001 or 0.0001. Also, use Adam optimizer for faster convergence.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried it and it didn't work. I don't think optimizer type would be the case

Comment: Try lowering the learning rate. A rate of 0.001 works the best in most cases.